# How to overcome 400 Bad Request while using google client api in android?

Tags: android, youtube, google-api-client

I am using google client api to integrate youtube in my android app. I am using this code,

```
YouTubeUrl url = new YouTubeUrl(VIDEOS_FEED);
    url.author = "searchstories";
    url.maxResults = 2;
    // build the HTTP GET request
    HttpRequest request;
    try {
        request = factory.buildGetRequest(url);
        // execute the request and the parse video feed
        VideoFeed feed = request.execute().parseAs(VideoFeed.class);
```

while getting the feed it throws com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request. First few times it worked properly and then it is giving 400 bad request. How to overcome this problem?  Plz help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actuall I was missing to add headers

GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();

headers.setApplicationName("TestApp/1.0");

headers.gdataVersion = "2";
request.headers = headers;

Adding the headers to the HttpRequest solved the 400 Bad Request Exception.
Enjoy...!!!

Comment: can u please tell me Which library includes GoogleHeaders ...thanx